# The regular expression to validate a phone number doesn't work

Tags: regex

I create a regular expression to validate a phone number, but it doesn't work.

```
<form>
<label for="phone">Phone number:</label>
<input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required 
pattern="^\d{10}$|^\d{3}([\s-\.])\d{3}\1\d{4}$">
<button>Submit comment</button>
</form>
```

I use "an123456" to test, it's not a phone number, but it passed. I changed the "\s" in the pattern to " ", the regular expression worked correctly. So what's wrong with the "\s"?

Comment: Yeah, use `pattern="\d{10}|\d{3}([\s.-])\d{3}\1\d{4}"`

Comment: Your pattern works correctly in regex101 using several flavours of regex. I can't see the problem. Some flavours recongnise less special symbols than others but \s is pretty univeral.

Comment: @Kendle It has nothing to do with `\s`. The problem is with overescaping a pattern compiled with `u` flag.

Comment: @Kendle - in a character class indicates a range. What would be the starting character of the range [\s-\.]

Comment: Sorry - yes I had displaced the hyphen to the end of the class to make it work. (When it is the first or last character in the class it is treated as a literal without escaping)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix your regex like this:

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="phone">Phone number:</label>
  <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" required pattern="\d{10}|\d{3}([\s.-])\d{3}\1\d{4}" />
  <button>Submit comment</button>
</form>
```

The final pattern will look like `^(?:\d{10}|\d{3}([\s.-])\d{3}\1\d{4})$` and it will match the full string due to automatically added anchors and the outer non-capturing group (no need adding them in the pattern).

Note that the `pattern` regex is compiled with `u` flag, and this means there are more escaping restrictions for the pattern. So, `-` must be at the end or start of the character class and you CAN'T escape the `.`, it MUST be unescaped since it is not any special regex metacharacter.